# Converting ArrayList into JSON Array, Java Programming

Tags: java, arrays, json

Hi there i know maybe this is stupid mistake, but i need your help.

i have code like this that getting an object from db using ArrayList then convert it to JSONArray

```
protected JSONArray statisticPesanan(){
    List<ListPesanan> det = new ArrayList();
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    try {
        //create JSONObject to executed
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM vstatisticpesanan";
        Connection conn;
        conn = datman.logOn();
        Statement statement = (Statement) conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);
        //add list to Array
        while (rs.next())
        { 
            ListPesanan psn = new ListPesanan(rs.getString(1), rs.getInt(2));
            det.add(psn);
        }
        //convert to JSON array
        for (int i=0; i < det.size(); i++) {
            jsonArray.add(det.get(i).jsonobject());
        }
    } catch (SQLException se) {
        Logger.getLogger(Analytics.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, se);
        java.lang.System.out.println("Error on Analytics Generate JSON Pesanan Statistics : " + se.toString());
    } 
    finally {
        datman.logOff(); 
    }    
    return jsonArray;
}
```

the output from servlet execution using this code

```
 public class chartGetTransaction extends HttpServlet {

/**
 * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
 * methods.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {
        /* Execution of JSON Chart */
        Analytics show = new Analytics();
        JSONArray array = show.getStatisticPesanan();
        for(int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++){
            out.print(array.get(i).toString());
        }
    } finally {
        out.close();
    }
}
```

the RESULT OUTPUT is like this:

```
{"1":"2013-10-12","2":3}{"1":"2013-11-16","2":2}{"1":"2013-12-23","2":4}{"1":"2014-02-11","2":10}
```

but i need the format like this::

```
[{"1":"2013-10-12","2":3},{"1":"2013-11-16","2":2},{"1":"2013-12-23","2":4},{"1":"2014-02-11","2":10}]
```

any ideas guys?

thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just print the `array` directly?

Comment: what do you mean? @SotiriosDelimanolis can u explain further?

Comment: `out.print(array.toString())` That's the whole point of those classes.

Comment: in this code: for(int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++){
            out.print(array.get(i).toString());
        } @SotiriosDelimanolis?

Comment: You are getting the output you see because you are printing individual objects from the array yourself.  You need to serialize the array directly.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, i see the problem is in my servlet. Stupid mistake. please create an answer then i will mark as answer.

Comment: @manish.in.java thanks for helping. i have figure the problem. :)

Comment: @randytan, not to be pedantic but `chartGetTransaction` as a class should be capitalized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `JSONArray` contains other json elements. In your case, it seems like it contains json objects.

When you do

```
JSONArray array = show.getStatisticPesanan();
for(int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++){
    out.print(array.get(i).toString());
}
```

you are printing (and concatenating) the individuals objects in the array. You don't want this. You want to print the array directly. Fortunately, `JSONArray#toString()` already does that serialization for you.

```
JSONArray array = show.getStatisticPesanan();
out.print(array.toString());
```

Comment: have u use Morris Chart in java page? https://github.com/morrisjs/morris.js @Sotirios Delimanolis

Comment: @randytan I have not.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using the for loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++){
    out.print(array.get(i).toString());
}
```

it will print the one - by - one for the requirement format you just have to use the below code..

```
StringWriter out = new StringWriter();
jsonArray.writeJSONString(out);
String jsonText = out.toString();
out.print(jsonText);
```

Comment: hi @Deepak, thanks for your reply. I have figure the wrong servlet code.

Comment: or try to print the jsonArray directly but i am not sure that will work or not.. **out.print(jsonArray);** I hope it should work as well..

Comment: hi @Deepak,same as Sotirios question, have u use Morris chart in your java page? github.com/morrisjs/morris.js